# Get registered hotkey for a command

Tags: vscode-extensions

Does VSCode API provide a way retrieve hotkey user set for a command? I could parse the `package.json`, but it will only give default hotkeys, not user's.

Comment: My guess is you would have to get and parse the `keybindings.json` yourself to get that info.

Comment: is it accessible from extension though?

Comment: That is what I mean, you get the user's `keybindings.json`  - it is stored in a standard location - and parse it.

Comment: Well, what is a "standard" location? each OS has different location and then there are portable versions...so how do you get the location of `keybindings.json`?